# Kotlin & Hibernate IllegalArgumentException: Can not set String field Job.name to Job

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, kotlin

I am trying to persist a single object with hibernate into a postgres db. The class looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "jobs")
data class Job(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Int? = 0,
    var name: String? = ""
)
```

I create a hibernate session with the following code:

```
fun createSessionFactory(targetClass: Class<*>): SessionFactory? {
    val registryBuilder = StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()

    if (sessionFactory == null) {
        val configuration = hashMapOf(
                Environment.DRIVER to "org.postgresql.Driver",
                Environment.URL to "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb",
                Environment.DIALECT to "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect",
                Environment.USER to "user",
                Environment.PASS to "password",
                Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO to "create"
        )


        registryBuilder.applySettings(configuration)
        serviceRegistry = registryBuilder.build()

        val sources = MetadataSources(serviceRegistry)
        sources.addAnnotatedClass(targetClass)
        val metadata = sources.metadataBuilder.build()

        sessionFactory = metadata.sessionFactoryBuilder.build()
    }
    return sessionFactory
}
```

When I try to store an instance ob the job class with:

```
override fun persistEntity(entity: Job) {
    val session = databaseSession.createSessionFactory(Job::class.java)!!.openSession()
    session.beginTransaction()
    session.save(entity)

    session.transaction.commit()
    session.close()
    databaseSession.destroySession()
}
```

I get the exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.String field Job.name to Job.

All this is implemented inside a spring boot application with multiple modules. To make sure that there is no problem with the dependencies between the modules I recreated the structure in an other project and there the same code works as expected.

Does anybody have an idea what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working. It turned out that spring devtools somehow are conflicting with kotlin and hibernate. After removing them from the project everything works nice.